# Move a excel graph so that it remains in view

Tags: excel, vba

I want to move a graph in excel so that it is always visible. If the user clicks on a certain cell the graph must move so that it is visible again. I know how to move the graph, but how do I get the y (or top) value of the top most visible cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to get a reference to range currently visible on screen

```
Set rngVisible = ActiveWindow.ActivePane.VisibleRange
```

This little demo will keep a particular shape located at the Top Left of the visible screen as the user changes the selection (coded in relevant Sheet module)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim rngVisible As Range

    Set rngVisible = ActiveWindow.ActivePane.VisibleRange
    Set shp = Me.Shapes("MyShape")

    shp.Top = rngVisible.Top
    shp.Left = rngVisible.Left
End Sub
```